# Debug .asp pages with visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, migration

I'm migrating a website made in classic asp to asp.net, but the asp.net dev server doesn't handle .asp pages.

Is it possible to make it run .asp pages? Maybe a custom httphandler for .asp?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running Winxp with IIS installed?  If so, here's what I do: hit the asp pages in the browser using your local IIS, and then open the folder where the ASP pages reside as a website project in VS. Go to the Debug menu, choose Attach to Process, and then look for the dllhost.exe process that is running under the IWAM_MACHINENAME user.  You also have to make sure the you have setup the virtual directory to allow ASP server-side debugging.  After attaching to that process, you can set breakpoints, etc. as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had to debug asp pages I found it was easier to insert a bunch of Response.Write()'s.  If you cant find a way to do it in VS, then this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to use traditional (or arcane!) methods to debug your asp pages in VS2005 (i.e. alert(), response.write() etc.)

Comment: Dang, I was hoping someone had a better way then my hack-o-rama idea.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not what you want to hear, but vs2005 doesn't support this. It was re-added into vs2008. Perhaps one of the free vs2008 express edtions might get you out of this hole?

Comment: I just tried with vwd2008, doesn't handle .asp page... says file type is not served

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by [patmortech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19090/patmortech) I would recommend that if you are testing a mixed tech site you attach to aspnet_wp to debug the .NET portions of the app.  This is also true if your app uses third-party ISAPI filters.

The Cassini server is good for pure .NET only.